# Template T4 - Use ConfigurationBuilder appsetting.json netstandard2.0

Tags: c#, t4, .net-standard-2.0

Im working on some code-generation stuff - using T4 RuntimTemplates.

The Template has to genereate some enums/strings reading a database.
I am able to generate this code by encoding the connection string, but when I try to load the ConnectionString using the class ConfigurationManager or ConfigurationBuilder is not possible.

We would like to replace this connection string in our pipelines.

Any example or suggestion to do this using a project in netstandard 2.0 ?

Getting keys from ConfigurationManger always returns null.

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Configuration" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Configuration" #>

<#
    var myVariable = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyConfigSetting"];
#>
```

Comment: Since the T4 engine doesn't have access to the configuration that is set up by a normal program.cs file, you'll have to do that bit manually.

Comment: @DavidG Do you mean hardcoding the connection string directly in the tt file?